# jQuery Siblings with sub Class?

Tags: jquery

I want to get all the "`siblings`" of the clicked element which has `'.divRe'` class which contains a  `'.divAbs'` class

http://jsbin.com/uyirim/edit#javascript,html

Why  it is not working ?

(Its length suppose to be '**1**'.)

Comment: I understand that English may not be your first language, but I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

The only sibling of the link is the `div` and it does not match the selector `.divRe .divAbs`. `$('.divRe').is('.divRe .divAbs')` returns `false`.

You want to combine it with `.find()`:

```
$(this).siblings(".divRe").find(".divAbs")
```

*Edit:* Seems like you are are really after `.has` instead of `.find`. Have a look at the other answers.

Comment: .divRe .divAbs says all the divRe which has inside them divAbs...no ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It depends on which function you are passing the selector to. Read the documentation again. It says `.siblings()` gets a list of all siblings of the element. In your case the only sibling is the `div`. It then only keeps those elements that match the selector, and the `div` does not match `.divRe .divAbs`. In this case the selector is *not* used for *finding* elements. It is used to *filter* on a already existing set of elements (the siblings).

Answer (score 2):

If the .divRe has more than one(say 2) .divAbs this

```
$(this).siblings(".divRe").find(".divAbs").length
```

will return 2

but this

```
$(this).siblings(".divRe").has(".divAbs").length
```

will give 1.

So for what you need use the [has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/) method.

Answer (score 0):

The `".divRe .divAbs"` selector matches the inside div `.divAbs`, which is not the siblings.

You can use `has()`:

```
$(this).siblings(".divRe").has(".divAbs").length
```

Comment: Your explanation is not correct. In this context `".divRe .divAbs"` would match an element which has a `divAbs` class and an ancestor with class `divRe`.

Comment: @FelixKling Yep, you are write.

Comment: @xdazz , this is not right. if you want both.a and .b so $(".a.b")